# Convert from List<List<? extends Object>> to List<List<SpecificType>>

Tags: java, compiler-errors

There is my problem, I've a function `listToSublists` I absolutely want to be generic so i've wrote this :

```
public static List<List<? extends Object>> listToSubLists(List<? extends Object> elements, int sublistsLength) {
    ....
}
```

And i want to call that function that way :

```
List<LigneMaj> datas = ...;
List<List<LigneMaj>> datasPaquets = BatchUtils.listToSubLists(datas, 100);
```

It appears that it is impossible to compile and I'm struggling to understand why i'm getting this error :

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<List<? extends Object>> to List<List<LigneMaj>>
```

Could someone explain what I am missing please?

Comment: Just make it a generic method, not with wildcards but with a proper type parameter T. BTW, `<? extends Object>` can be written simply as `<?>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static <T> List<List<T>> listToSubLists(List<T> elements, int sublistsLength) {
        if (!elements.isEmpty()) {
            List<List<T>> result = new ArrayList<>();

            final int sublists = ((elements.size() - 1) / sublistsLength) + 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < sublists; i++) {
                result.add(new ArrayList<>());
            }

            for (int currentIndex = 0; currentIndex < elements.size(); currentIndex++) {
                final T elem = elements.get(currentIndex);
                result.get(currentIndex / sublistsLength).add(elem);
            }

            return result;
        } else {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks so i was just missing the first <T> in the signature... I wasn't asking for the functional code but thanks.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.